# Longest run of heads (coin tossing)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

The following problem comes from an old exam (introduction to probability). I have seen that there are similar questions on the forum, but most of them seem to be a bit more advanced and none of the answers I have found is truly elementary and short (and it should be the case, as this is an exam problem).

> Let $X_n$ be the length of the longest run of heads in $n$ coin tosses. For example, if we obtain
> $$\textbf{HHTTHTHHHTH},$$
> then $X_{11}=3.$ Prove that:

1. $\mathbb{P}(X_n\ge \lambda\log_{2}n)\longrightarrow 0$ $\ \ \text{for} \ \lambda>1,$
2. $\mathbb{P}(X_n\ge \lambda\log_{2}n)\longrightarrow 1$ $\ \ \text{for} \ 0<\lambda<1.$

I have failed in solving this exercise (after a long try). My first impression was that this is an exercise for the Borel-Cantelli lemma (but I am not so sure anymore). Do You know how to do this in an efficient way? Is this exercise rally about the $\textbf{B-C}$ $\textit{lemma}$ or something different? I will be glad for any insight or help.

Comment: It's a zero-one law, so it's not necessarily about Borel-Cantelli. There are other zero-one laws that could be useful.